# how to destroy session in asp.net for grid view

Tags: asp.net

i have set sesssion lik this

```
Session["page" + GridView1.PageIndex] = values;
```

Now hwen next time on ok button click hen i regenerate i fresh copy of gridview. It's first column which hold the checkbox automatically takes values from the checkbox.
So i want that the session should be destroyed how to achieve this for all page index of datagrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session.Abandon();`

> The Abandon method destroys all the
>   objects stored in a Session object and
>   releases their resources. If you do
>   not call the Abandon method
>   explicitly, the server destroys these
>   objects when the session times out.

A worthy note though:

> When the Abandon method is called, the
>   current Session object is queued for
>   deletion but is  not actually deleted
>   until all of the script commands on
>   the current page have been processed.
>   This means that you can access
>   variables stored in the Session object
>   on the same page as the call to the
>   Abandon method but not in any
>   subsequent Web pages.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(VS.90).aspx).

---

#### Edit 1:

In reply to not wanting to destroy the entire session, Can you not simply remove the item from the session then? E.g.: `Session.Remove("page" + GridView1.PageIndex);`?

---

#### Edit 2:

`Session.Clear()` removes all keys and objects from the current session.

Comment: will it abandon for all page session.
And if i am using a session for some other object will it destroy that . if so i dont want that at all so please suggest the alternet